# how to hide and unhide an element in angular

Tags: angular

I am using angular 8 I want to hide and unhide an element based on condition.
here is my requirement:

I have breadcrumb like this:

Html:

```
 <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
   <ol class="breadcrumb">
     <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a>{{ bd_main }}</a></li>
     <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page" [style.visibility]="bd_submain ? 
     'visible':'hidden'". >Submenu</li>
  </ol>
 </nav>
```

component.ts:

```
 export class MonthlyComponent implements OnInit {
 bd_main= "Home";
 bd_submain = true;

  }
```

I tried this way but it is not working can anyone tell me what is wrong with this?

Comment: You can use `*ngIf = bd_submain` to show/hide an element and change the value of `bd_submain` to true/false to show/hide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed the '.'(dot) in Html page and I changed bd_submain = False in ts file

Answer (score 0):

u can use ng-style,
this example :

```
<div ng-style="{'visibility': bd_submain?'visible':'hidden'}">...</div>

or 

[ngStyle]="{'visibility':bd_submain=== true ? 'visible' : 'hidden' }"
```